# Handling models with optional members (can be none) properly?

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch

I have a subclass of torch.nn.Module, whose initialiser have the following form:
(in class A)

```
def __init__(self, additional_layer=False):
    ...
    if additional_layer:
        self.additional = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(8,3)).to(self.device)
    else:
        self.additional = None
    ...
    ...
```

I train with additional_layer=True and save the model with `torch.save`. The object I save is `model.state_dict()`. Then I load the model for inference. But then I get the following error:

```
model.load_state_dict(best_model["my_model"])

RuntimeError: Error(s) in loading state_dict for A:
        Unexpected key(s) in state_dict: "additional.0.weight"
```

Is using an optional field which can be None disallowed?? How to handle this properly? [Also posted [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/pytorch/comments/18w4ipz/handling_models_with_optional_members_can_be_none/)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a problem specifically related to the value being `None`; you'd have the same issue if you were to use any other `nn.Module` (as the value of `additional` attribute) that is not a sequence (the `0` after `additional`) and does not have a parameter named `weight` in the first `nn.Module` in the sequential module (the `weight` after `additional.0`).

The issue is, in your *train* mode, when you initialized your model, you have passed `True` for `additional_layer` argument i.e.:

```
model = YourModelClass(additional_layer=True)
```

hence `self.additional` is set to a `nn.Module` (`nn.Sequential` specifically). So, the `model` object's `state_dict` would have the parameters for the module referred to by the `self.additional` attribute.

Now, when you re-initialized the model for *inference*, you didn't have the additional layers as you initialized the model presumably by one of the following:

```
model = YourModelClass(additional_layer=False)
model = YourModelClass()
```

This time there the `self.additional` i.e. `model.additional` attribute would be `None`. As a result, when you call `model.load_state_dict` and pass it the state dict that was saved earlier in *train* mode (when additinal layer was there), it gives you the exception that all the keys for the `additional` attribute are missing.

Assuming you have the correct conditional setup in the `forward` method when `self.additional` is `None`, you can ignore the exception and bypass the loading of missing keys/parameters by setting the `strict` argument to `False` while using `load_state_dict`:

```
model.load_state_dict(best_model["my_model"], strict=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `torch.nn.Identity()` rather than `None`.

Or you can pass the tensor in `forward()` function.